# Redirect to a URL similar to a get URL

Tags: php, html, web, localhost

I am designing a website similar to Facebook, Instagram... Which have a profile page for each user.
My question is: If a user wants to view the profile of another one, is this technique usable? (the user id here will be for example 123)

```
http://localhost/viewprofile.php?user_id=123
```

Then I will get the user_id from `$_GET` and retrieve the user information from the database and display them.

Comment: I need to redirect to a page that has all the user information without setting up a page for each user. So I will make a template page for all users and fill it up with all their information from the database, but I will fill the URL with the user's ID to then retrieve it with the  ` $_GET ` in the template page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a good technique, user gets the profile using the GET parameter, otherwise you can use POST but since there is no delicate information so this approach as you mentioned is fine.